# Translating month names into number using only XSL version 1.0

Tags: datetime, xslt

I'm pulling in a custom XML feed from a client's server. I have no control over this XML format. In order to restructure the XML structure I'm using XSLT by running [wget](http://man.cx/wget) and [xsltproc](http://man.cx/xsltproc) to apply a custom style sheet under RHEL 5. Things are working just fine until when we need to do a bit of date conversions.

The feed coming is as such...

```
...
<event>
   <date>October 3, 2013</date>
   <time>2:00 PM - 4:00 PM</time>
   <moar_xml_here/>
</event>
...
```

However I need a distinct `<startDateTime>` and `<endDateTime>`.

I'm currently converting the date portion in a template as follows. I'm looking over this code and wondering if there is a better way.

```
<xsl:template match="date">
    <!-- year first -->
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(., ','))"/>

    <!-- month  -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'January')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-01"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'February')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-02"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'March')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-03"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'April')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-04"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'May')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-05"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'June')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-06"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'July')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-07"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'August')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-08"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'September')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-09"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'October')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-10"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'November')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-11"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(., 'December')">
            <xsl:value-of select="-12"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

    <!-- Get everything before the comma, find the position of the space, and return the remaining value (day as date) -->
    <xsl:variable name="working_to_day" select="normalize-space(substring-before(. , ','))"/>

    <xsl:variable name="space_pos" select="string-length(normalize-space(substring-before(. , ' ')))+1"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="string('-')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(substring($working_to_day, $space_pos), ' ', '0'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want two digit values, but note

```
<xsl:value-of select="-08"/>
```

is same as

```
<xsl:value-of select="-8"/>
```

and makes `-8`

I'd probably use substring-before as in:

$ saxon date.xml date.xsl

```
original:
 -1

new:
  01


original:
 -10

new:
  10
```

---

```
<x>

<date>January</date>

<date>October</date>

</x>
```

---

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="date">
original:
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'January')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-01"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'February')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-02"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'March')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-03"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'April')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-04"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'May')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-05"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'June')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-06"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'July')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-07"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'August')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-08"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'September')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-09"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'October')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-10"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'November')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-11"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="contains(., 'December')">
   <xsl:value-of select="-12"/>
  </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
```

new:

```
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(
                        string-length(substring-before(
     'JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec',
         substring(.,1,3))) div 3 + 1,'00')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you David, I'm impressed by the concise logic applied here! I must admit it took a second to fully get what was happening. For what it's worth: I learned a technique this morning that I'll take forward in this and future projects.